# Display data on a map using leaflet and fade

Tags: json, ajax, geojson, fade

How display on a map using modal fade to enter the longitude and latitude of the point to be displayed. The code below displays nothing. But when I use the json format url in modal fade, the information in json format.I don't know how to use the class modal fade in data mapping. Should the url in modal fade be json or html format?
I got this error : TypeError: InondationDataPoint() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'longitude' and 'latitude'

```
#models.py
class Even(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    date_reported = models.DateField()
    longitude = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)
    latitude = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)
    geom = models.PointField(srid=4326, null=True, blank=True,)
    @property
    def longitude(self):
        return self.geom.x
    @property
    def latitude(self):
        return self.geom.y
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name 

#urls.py
urlpatterns = [
    path('evenement_point/',      views.EvenementDataPoint,name="evenement_point"),
    path('evenement_map_point/', 
    views.evenement_map_point,name="evenement_map_point"),
]

#views.py
def evenement_map_point(request):
    longitude=request.POST['longitude']
    latitude=request.POST['latitude']
    all_evens = Even.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'even_map_point.html', {'all_evens': 
    all_evens, 'longitude':longitude, 'latitude':latitude})


def EvenementDataPoint(request, longitude, latitude):
    ref_location = Point(float(longitude), float(latitude))
    name = serialize('geojson', 
    Even.objects.filter(geom=ref_location))
    return HttpResponse(name,content_type='json')

#even_map_point.html
var even = new L.GeoJSON.AJAX("{% url 'evenement :evenement_point' %}", {
    pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
    return L.marker(latlng, {
        icon: L.icon({
        iconUrl: "/static/img/icons/red.png",
        iconSize: [28, 32],
        iconAnchor: [12, 28],
        popupAnchor: [0, -25]
    }),
    title: feature.properties.name, 
    riseOnHover: true
  });
},
onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
    var content = "<table class='table table-striped table-bordered table- 
        condensed'>" + "<tr><th>Name</th><td>" + feature.properties.name + "</td> 
        </tr>" + "<tr><th>Date</th><td>" + feature.properties.date ;
    layer.on({
        click: function (e) {
            layer.bindPopup(content).openPopup(e.latlng);   
        }
    });
  }
  }).addTo(map);


#index.html with modal fade
<div class="container-fluid"> 
    <div class="modal fade" id="evenmapPoint">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Menu de Recherche</h4>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times; 
                    </button>
                 </div>
                 <div class="modal-body">
                     <form id="evenmappoint" method="POST" action="{% url 
                     'evenement:evenement_map_point' %}">
                     <!--<form id="evenmappoint" method="POST" action="{% url 
                     'evenement:evenement_point' %}">-->  <!--ok point displayed in 
                     format json-->
                         <div class="row">
                             <div class="col-sm-6">
                                 <div class="form-group">
                                     {% csrf_token %}
                                     <input class="form-control valid" 
                                     name="longitude" id="name" type="number" 
                                     step="any" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" 
                                     onblur="this.placeholder = 'Enter your 
                                     longitude'" placeholder="Enter your longitude">    
                                 </div>
                             </div>
                             <div class="col-sm-6">
                                 <div class="form-group">
                                     {% csrf_token %}
                                     <input class="form-control valid" 
                                     name="latitude" id="name" type="number" 
                                     step="any" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" 
                                     onblur="this.placeholder = 'Enter your 
                                     latitude'" placeholder="Enter your latitude">
                                 </div>
                             </div>
                        </div>
                  </form> 
             </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="submit" form="evenmappoint" class="btn btn- 
                     success">Chercher</button> 
                     <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data- 
                      dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                 </div>
              </div>
         </div>        
    </div>
```

Comment: You can check [this tutorial](https://youtube.com/playlist?list=PLyWyQBSWLw1OUfqcPzO6AceuGpC5gr-_n) on youtube. In this playlist, you will find the Create and read option for the user marker.

Comment: witch video on the playlist?

Comment: All, These are the short videos!

Comment: I have seen all the videos, unfortunately that is not what I am looking for. I want to search for a point if it exists in my database and then display it on the map.