# check if a point inside a rectangle and cercle

Tags: ajax, leaflet, modal-dialog, fade

Using Django and Leaflet How to check if a point is inside a:

- rectangle
- cercle

the coordinates of the rectangle are entered via a modal fade form

Comment: Post the code, impossible to help you otherwise.

Comment: Can you give us a short example of how the input is given? also where does the info about the circle ( cercle? ) come from?

Comment: I have already posted this problem for the case of a point in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69563142/display-data-on-a-map-using-leaflet-and-fade
This problem I have not yet resolved. while waiting to adjust it, I wanted to have an idea how to display all the points of a rectangle and also those of a circle of radius R.