# Communication and data sharing between two functions using django

Tags: json, django, function, request

Qui peut m’orienter comment utiliser les résultats d’une fonction comme paramètres d’entrées pour une autre fonction ?

This is my code :

```
def even_point(request):
    longitude=request.POST['longitude']
    latitude=request.POST['latitude'] 
    ref_location = Point(float(longitude), float(latitude))
    all_evens = Even.objects.all()

    return render(request, 'even_map_point.html', {'all_evens': all_evens,
    'longitude':longitude, 'latitude':latitude, 'ref_location':ref_location})


def EvenDataPoint(request, ref_location): 
    name = serialize('geojson', Evenobjects.filter(geom__contains=ref_location))

    return HttpResponse(name,content_type='json')
```

I have the following error:

TypeError: EvenementDataPoint() missing 1 required positional argument: 'ref_location'

How do I get the second function to recognize the location value calculated in the first function?

Comment: I think more information is necessary for you to get some help. For instance the whole traceback from the error. From what you wrote, EvanDataPoint is being called without the required arguments, but I can't tell where the error is happening, apparently not in the code you shared.

Comment: for more details for my complete code see : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69563142/display-data-on-a-map-using-leaflet-and-fade

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way to achieve this is to use django session  something like this

```
def even_point(request):
    longitude=request.POST['longitude']
    latitude=request.POST['latitude'] 
    ref_location = Point(float(longitude), float(latitude))
    request.session['ref_location'] = ref_location #nouveau
    all_evens = Even.objects.all()

    return render(request, 'even_map_point.html', {'all_evens': all_evens,
    'longitude':longitude, 'latitude':latitude, 'ref_location':ref_location})


def EvenDataPoint(request): 
    ref_location = request.session.get('ref_location',None) #nouveau
    name = serialize('geojson', Even.objects.filter(geom__contains=ref_location))

    return HttpResponse(name,content_type='json')
```

**Make Sure to delete the session after you finished to filter it**